# What's difference Between module and component?

Tags: frontend

In front-end development, components(web components and reactive components) is the future, but how do you describe the difference between module and component? Is module categorized as only js files?

Comment: In what context? Often the nouns "module" and "component" have specific definitions for a given platform or system (for example, COM and .NET)

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/178927/is-there-a-difference-between-a-component-and-a-module